# C# WPF how to change frame source through combobox selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, frame

fellow Programmers,

I have a combobox, and a frame in my XAML.
However I want to be able to change the source of the frame, when the selected value from the combobox list is different from the default.

CODE:

*XAML*

## Frame

```
    <DockPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="comboFrame" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Source="pan.xaml"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

## ComboBox

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="NumberBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="160,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1" ItemsSource="{Binding elements, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, StringFormat=\{0:X\}}" BorderThickness="0">

        <ComboBoxItem Content="3"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="4"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="6"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="7"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>   

    </ComboBox>
```

*C#*

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        
        string stX = Convert.ToString(NumberBox.SelectedItem);

        comboFrame.Navigate(new Uri("pan.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        if (stX == "3")
        {

            comboFrame.Navigate(new Uri("pan1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }

    }
```

In conclusion - I want to be able to change source of the frame for selections, different than 2 in the combobox. The default source is pan.xaml which is selection 2.
Basically dependent on the number. The panels all contain other comboboxes.
Panel contains 2 CBs (ComboBoxes), Panel 1 contains 3 CBs, etc. until Panel 6 which contains 8 CBs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MVVM? I could think of base class for items (ViewModels), then `DataTemplate` for each `ViewModel`. Bindings: `Combobox.SourceItems` to `ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>`, `Combobox.SelectedItem` to `Frame.Source` (possible via converter).

Comment: Could use DataTriggers on the ComboBox that fire off a ChangePropertyAction to the source of the frame as the TargetProperty if you wanted to do it just with xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

New code:

*XAML* - added names to the contents;

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="NumberBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="160,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1" ItemsSource="{Binding elements, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, StringFormat=\{0:X\}}" BorderThickness="0">

        <ComboBoxItem Name="TwoBoxItem" Content="2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="ThreeBoxItem" Content="3"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="FourBoxItem" Content="4"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="FiveBoxItem" Content="5"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="SixBoxItem" Content="6"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="SevenBoxItem" Content="7"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="EightBoxItem" Content="8"/>

    </ComboBox>
```

*C#* - used the XAML content name, checked if selection is equal to it and then used dispatcher.invoke to redirect the frame to the URL of the page with the relevant number of comboboxes.

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        Uri oneX = new Uri("pan.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

        if (NumberBox.SelectedItem == TwoBoxItem)
        {

            comboFrame.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
            {

                comboFrame.Source = oneX;

            }

            );

        }
```

Thanks to all for your answers and I hope this helps someone.